# Actuary Exam Question dealing with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Assume a policyholder is four times more likely to file two claims as to file exactly three claims. Assume also that the number X of claims of this policyholder is Poisson. What is $E(X^2)$?

Here's what I have so far:

$ 4(P(X=3))=P(X=2)=(\lambda^2*e^{-2})/2!\\
P(X=3)=(\lambda^3*e^{-3})/3!$

Solving this algebra gives us that $\lambda=2.039$

Since we're asked to find the 2nd moment about X, isn't that just $\lambda$? The answer to$ E(X^2)$ is 21/16. why is that and what procedure do you use to even get a fraction here?

Comment: You should have $P(X=2)=(\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda})/2!,$ $P(X=3)=(\lambda^{3}e^{-\lambda})/3!.$ This should give you a rational $\lambda,$ and finally, $\lambda=\mathrm{Var}(X)=E(X^{2})-E(X)^{2}=E(X^{2})-\lambda^{2},$ so $E(X^{2})=\lambda(1+\lambda).$

Comment: $\lambda = Var(X)$, not $E(X^2).$

Answer (score 0):

As RideTheWavelet mentioned, you should have $$P(X=2)=\frac{λ^2  e^{−λ}}{2!},\qquad
P(X=3)=\frac{λ^{3}  e^{−λ}}{3!}.$$

Because you know that $P(X=2) = 4  P(X=3),$ this gives you $\frac{λ^2  e^{−λ}}{2!} = 4\frac{λ^3  e^{−λ}}{3!}$.

This can be rewritten as $\frac{λ^2  e^{−λ}}{2!} = 4 λ \frac{λ^2  e^{−λ}}{3!}.$

Dividing both sides by $\frac{4 λ^2  e^{−λ}}{3!}$ leaves you with $λ = \frac{λ^2  e^{−λ}}{2!}  \frac{3!}{4  λ^2  e^{−λ}},$ which simplifies to just $\frac{3}{4}.$

Because this is a Poisson Distribution,$ μ = σ^2 = λ = \frac{3}{4}. $

$σ^2 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = E[X^2] - μ^2. $

You're trying to solve for $E[X^2].$

Rearranging the equation, you have $E[X^2] = σ^2 + μ^2 = λ + λ^2 = \frac{3}{4} + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{21}{16}.$

I hope this helps!